# Laravel API Wrapper, Group methods in subclasses

Tags: php, class, laravel

I'm working on my first API Wrapper as a Laravel package, it's working for now but all my methods ( getCompanies, getDepartments, ... ) are in **the same class**

> Now I'm wondering if it's difficult to split up methods and group them in subclasses.

For example, now I'm calling the getCompanies as follows.

```
myApi::getCompanies();
```

I was wondering if it's not better to have

```
myApi::companies()->all();
```

What would be a good way to go about this? Or is it better to leave all methods in one file?

This is my package structure

[image]

And this is my main class code

```
<?php namespace Notflip\Teamleader;

class Teamleader {

    private $api_secret;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api_secret = config('teamleader.API_SECRET');
    }

    public function getDepartments()
    {
        return $this->call("getDepartments");
    }

    private function call($endpoint, $params = [])
    {
        $params['api_group'] = $this->api_group;
        $params['api_secret'] = $this->api_secret;

        $url = $this->api_base_url . $endpoint . '.php';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

        $api_output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($api_output);
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could be creating a separate client and create separate implementation parts of the API that require the client.

E.g.

```
Class `Client` {
  // implements the actual curl 
  public function get($path, $params = []);
}
```

And then create another class that grabs the client and does work with it:

```
class Departments {
   public function all(){
     $data = $this->getClient()->get();
   }
}
```